# ~foo(arguments); What does "~" mean in this code snippet in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

[code snippet of unirest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a35II.png)

As you can see above, **arrayIndexOf** refers to a function. When invoking the arrayIndexOf function,
is it necessary to put "~" before "arrayIndexOf"? I try to change "~arrayIndexOf(value, field)" to "arrayIndexOf(value, field)". And it works as the same? Is there anything I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In JavaScript, the tilde ~ Bitwise NOT operator is commonly used right
>   before an indexOf() to do a boolean check (truthy/falsy) on a string.
>   On its own, indexOf() returns the index number of a String object
>   passed in. So if -1 is returned it will be turned into 0 which is
>   falsy.

Source: https://wsvincent.com/javascript-tilde/